# Order of the iterations of entries in an Ignite cache and seek method

Tags: ignite

What is the ordering of the keys in an Ignite cache (without using indexing) and is it possible to do the equivalent of the following RocksDB snippet

> ```
>     try (final RocksIterator rocksIterator =
>             rocksDB.newIterator(columnFamilyHandleList.get(1))) {
>         for (rocksIterator.seek(prefixKey);
> ```

i.e. jump to the next entry starting with a given byte[] or String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you'd do that in Ignite is by using SQL.

```
        var query = new SqlFieldsQuery("select x,y,z from table where z like ? order by x").setArgs("prefix%");
        try (var cursor = cache.query(query)) {
            for (var r : cursor) {
                Long id = (Long) r.get(0);
                BigDecimal value = (BigDecimal) r.get(1);
                String name = (String) r.get(2);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. That's probably using the indexing with Lucene under the bonnet. I was wondering whether there was a more 'native' way of doing it.

Comment: No, it doesn't use Lucene (though you _can_ use full text search). Ignite currently uses the H2 parser, but the indexing, storage, etc., is all unique to Ignite.